# Condición where <= día concreto de la semana anterior

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente campo **SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK**. ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta `where` que diga que este campo tiene que tener información sea menor o igual que el sábado de la semana anterior a las 6:00?

Si me podéis indicar como seleccionar cualquier día de esta semana o la anterior como condición me vendría también genial.

¡Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, para determinar el sábado de la semana anterior, puedes basarte en una consulta como la siguiente:

```
set datefirst 1;
declare @fecha date = getdate();
select dateadd(DAY, -2, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @fecha), 0))
```

Ejecutando esto el día de hoy, 19 de abril del 2021, me da el siguiente resultado, que es correcto.

```
2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
```

Entonces, si quieres filtrar la información que sea anterior al último sábado a las 6AM, haz algo como:

```
select *
  from MiTabla
 where MiCampo <= dateadd(hour, 6, dateadd(DAY, -2, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)))
```

La *fórmula* ha cambiado un poco, pues ahora le estoy agregando las 6 horas, además de basarme en `getdate()` para obtener siempre la fecha de hoy.

Para comprobar que el dato producido es correcto, hice esta prueba, que genera fecha consecutivas para un par de semanas a partir del 17/4/2021:

```
with 
N as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) N 
  from sys.all_columns
)
, f as (
select dateadd(day, N, cast('20210416' as date)) fecha
  from N
 where N < 15
)
select   f.Fecha
       , dateadd(DAY, -2, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, fecha), 0)) UltimoSabado
  from f;
```

Que me retorna el siguiente resultado, que considero correcto:

```
Fecha      UltimoSabado
---------- -----------------------
2021-04-17 2021-04-10 00:00:00.000
2021-04-18 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-19 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-20 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-21 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-22 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-23 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-24 2021-04-17 00:00:00.000
2021-04-25 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000
2021-04-26 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000
2021-04-27 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000
2021-04-28 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000
2021-04-29 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000
2021-04-30 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000

(14 rows affected)

Completion time: 2021-04-19T03:00:02.4321953-06:00
```

Answer (score 6):

Para seleccionar un día en concreto puedes usar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK FROM X WHERE SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK = '2021-04-19'
```

Para hacer la consulta sobre la semana anterior a la actual puedes utilizar intervalos, como por ejemplo esta consulta:

```
SELECT SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK FROM X WHERE SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK = WEEK(now()) - 1;
```

Comment: Pero, ¿y si lo que quiero es que siempre sea <= que el sábado de la semana anterior?

Comment: Dependiendo del formato de fecha que tengas en tu base de datos, puedes utilizar `SELECT SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK FROM X WHERE SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK < '2021-04-19'` en caso de que quieras incluir el día, usa los dos signos `<=`.

Comment: Creo que me estoy explicando mal. Mi fecha esta en formato (dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss). La consulta se va a ejecutar todos los días de la semana. Y quiero que la consulta siempre saque los registros en los cuales el campo tiene una fecha <= que el Sábado a las 6:00 de la semana anterior. No puedo poner una fecha fija ya que se va a realizar la consulta diariamente y el sábado de la semana anterior cambia semanalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Primero se debe establecer el Domingo como el primer día de la semana. Lugo con el siguiente código se obtiene la fecha del último Sábado a las 6:00 PM. Con la fecha obtenida se puede realizar la comparación.

```
    SET DATEFIRST 7 ;
    DECLARE @lastSatunday DATETIME =  GETDATE() - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())   -- Obtener el sábado pasado
    SELECT @lastSatunday = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @lastSatunday))   -- Dejar la fecha con hora 00:00:00
    DECLARE @targetDateTime  DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR,18,@lastSatunday)      -- Fijar el DateTime a las 6:00PM
    SELECT @targetDateTime
```

Comment: Esto funcionará solo si en la configuración default de la base de datos el primer día de la semana es domingo, y fallará en otros casos.

Comment: Eso tiene solución dentro del mismo ámbito sin afectar la configuración global de MSSQL. La siguiente línea fija el Domingo como primer día de la semana para poder ejecutar las sentencias sin problemas. SET DATEFIRST 7 ;

Comment: Todo tiene solución, pero EMHO, esa es información vital que debieras incluir en la respuesta y no dejar en un comentario. Un saludo.